# how does xv6 use interrupts to schedule I/O requests to disk

Tags: io, interrupt, xv6

So basically Have just started studying xv6 and how it works. At the momenet I am particularity looking at interrupts and ide.c.

I know that xv6 source code includes a working IDE driver in ide.c. Also that IDE disk presents a simple interface to the Disk system, consisting of four types of register: control, command block, status, and error. These registers are available by reading or writing to specific I/O addresses using the in and out I/O instructions.

What I am struggling to understand is how does the xv6 operating system uses interrupts to schedule I/O requests to the disk?

Answer (score 1):

xv6 doesn't use interrupts to schedule I/O requests but uses interrupts for getting 'work done' events from the disk IDE.
After receiving an interrupt the kernel then checks whether the operation succeeded or not and updates the relevant struct buf.

The in and out assembly commands are used by xv6 kernel to command the disk IDE with new instructions and to receive data when it was notified ready when the IDE invoked the CPU with an interrupt.